There was a null output problem during scrape using the Puppeteer
I'm trying to scrape all of meaning and similar word data from this site    https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=${variable}
[ex)https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=win]
the scrape result is null
 async function web(word){
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false});
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto('https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query='+encodeURIComponent(word),{waitUntil:'networkidle0'});
  console.log('https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query='+encodeURIComponent(word))
  let meandata = await page.$$(".section.section_keyword .mean");
  let mean = await page.evaluate(elements => {
    return elements.map(element => element.textContent);
}, meandata);

  let sidata = await page.$$(".component_summary _thesaurusSwiper .word");
  let si = await page.evaluate(elements => {
    return elemenst.map(element => element.textContent);
}, sidata);

  await browser.close();

  const result = {mean,si}
  return result;
};

    app.post('/index',whlo,async function(req,res){
  if(req.body.added){
    const word = req.body.added;
    const result = await web(word);
    console.log(result)
  })

output
https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=word
{
min: [
null, null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null, null,
null
],
si: [
null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, null,
null, null
]
}
the link is correct but the output is null
i think there may be a problem with the code let meandata = await page.$$(".mean"); or html code of that site but i dont know what is wrong although i've seen some similar questions in stack overflow
expect
{
min: [
이기다, (경기 등에서 이겨 무엇을) 따다[타다/차지[쟁취]하다], 승리, 근로 장려책, [타도 인플레이션] ((Gerald R. Ford 대통령 시대의 슬로건)),
남자 이름(Winfred, Winston의 애칭), 전투원정보통신망]
si: [
prevail, ˌwin ˈout, triumph, win the ˈday,
come out on ˈtop]
}

In general, avoid element handles. Prefer $$eval for most scraping tasks, along with waitForSelector to ensure the data you want is on the page before you scrape it:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const definitionSel = "#searchPage_entry .mean";
  const thesaurusSel =
    ".component_summary._thesaurusSwiper .word";
  await page.waitForSelector(thesaurusSel);
  const definitions = await page.$$eval(definitionSel, els =>
    els.map(el => ({
      definition: [...el.childNodes].at(-1).textContent.trim(),
      type: el.querySelector(".word_class")?.textContent.trim(),
      mark: el.querySelector(".mark")?.textContent.trim(),
    }))
  );
  const thesaurus = await page.$$eval(thesaurusSel, els =>
    els.map(el => el.textContent.trim())
  );
  console.log(definitions);
  console.log(thesaurus);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Output:
[
  { definition: '이기다', type: 'Verb' },
  { definition: '(경기 등에서 이겨 무엇을) 따다[타다/차지[쟁취]하다]', type: 'Verb' },
  { definition: '승리', type: 'Noun' },
  { definition: '근로 장려책', type: 'Noun' },
  {
    definition: '[타도 인플레이션] ((Gerald R. Ford 대통령 시대의 슬로건))',
    type: 'Noun, Intransitive verb'
  },
  { definition: '남자 이름(Winfred, Winston의 애칭)', type: 'Noun' },
  { definition: '전투원정보통신망', mark: '군사' }
]
[
  'prevail',
  'ˌwin ˈout',
  'triumph',
  'win the ˈday',
  'come out on ˈtop'
]

If you just want the definitions, you can use
const definitions = await page.$$eval(definitionSel, els =>
  els.map(el => [...el.childNodes].at(-1).textContent.trim())
);

You can speed this up by blocking images and resources you don't need, and you can avoid the DOM by intercepting the API response that contains the data (search the network tab for "Gerald" or something like that to find it).
Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked blog post.
